# recv() is getting blocked for the last bytes of chunk in case of file transfer

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, gcc

Using socket programing I'm trying to transfer the file. Locally it works fine. But on n/w it works sometime and sometime it didn't.

```
#define MAXBUFFER 512
```

sender code:

```
// sending file data to the peer
FILE *sfile;
sfile=fopen(srcname,"rb");    
int total_s_byte=0;
while((r_byte=fread(data,1,MAXBUFFER,sfile))>0)
{
    s_byte=send(nsfd,data,r_byte,0);
    if(s_byte==-1)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed in sending\n");
        break;
    }
    total_s_byte+=s_byte;
}
printf("Total byte sent:%d\n",total_s_byte);
recv(nsfd,data,MAXBUFFER,0);
fclose(sfile);
close(nsfd);
```

Receiver

```
FILE *dfile;
dfile=fopen(dstname,"wb");
size_t total_r_byte=0;
//printf("\n\tStarting File download ....\n\t  File name: %s \n\t  File size: %ld\n",file_name,file_size);
while ((r_byte=recv(sfd,data,MAXBUFFER,0)) > 0)
{
     fwrite(data, 1, r_byte , dfile);
     total_r_byte+=r_byte;
     if(file_size == total_r_byte)
     {
        send(sfd,"ack",4,0);
        break;
     }
}
printf("\n------------------------#[Download Status]#-----------------------------------\n");
if(file_size == total_r_byte)
{
    printf("\n\tFile '%s' downloaded Successfully !!!\n",file_name);
}
else
{
    printf("\n\tError: Failed in downloading file %s \n",file_name);
}
printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

fclose(dfile);
close(sfd);
```

What is happing that sender send all files data. But recevier didn't last the last chuck it goes into block state?
What I'm thinking is that it is waiting for more data to come. But there is no more data to send. Because of it both sender and receiver went into dead lock state.

Not able to fix this issue.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that everything that is sent across will actually be received undisturbed. Depending on your transport, this isn't necessarily the case. If only one of your network packets is lost in transit, the receiver will wait forever and never send an *ack*, thus deadlock occurs. Is that UDP, by any chance?

Comment: tofro I,m using TCP. How to resolve this isse?

Comment: TCP should be safe - disregard the comment. How does the receiver get the *expected number of bytes*, i.e. `file_size` are you sure sender and receiver agree on that?

Comment: How is `r_byte` defined?

Comment: For debugging purpose set `MAXBUFFER` to `1`. Also log the bytes sent and received, as well as their totals. Make sure to use `size_t` everywhere, with the exception to where `send()`'s and `recv()`'s results go, use `ssize_t`for those. Also make file_size `unsigned`.

Comment: If you try to read more bytes than have been sent it will block, it will not return with a short message. So first you have to send the length. The recipient will know to stop when it has read that many bytes, then it can send the acknowledgement.